# Does the number 1 headband give the power of a god?

Tags: anime, afro-samurai

In Afro Samurai, it seems everybody is fighting to get the number 1 headband.  In most accounts about the number 1 headband, they say you become "like a god." But when Afro faced Justice, in the end, Justice was still mortal.  So that raises the question, **what god-like qualities does one acquire when possessing the number 1 headband?**

Comment: The godlike quality is "regard". You would be looked at as the god of battle.

Comment: Did you watch the same fight as me? https://youtu.be/F-DEv6mp8Bk?t=95
He did not seem particularly mortal to me.What other mortal do you know of that does not require their head to be connected to their body to continue fighting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The headband doesn't give **any** power.  It's just a normal head band.  The only reason why people want it, is because who ever owns it is the most powerful fighter.

The #1 headband on a persons head would mean that that person is the strongest fighter.  So other people would challenge #1 to try to become #1.  If the *succeed*, the take the headband and become the strongest person.  If they fail, they would probably die by the hands of the #1 fighter.

The reason why I'm using "fighter" instead of Samurai is because not all people who competed for the band were samurais.

Answer (score 2):

(Spoiler for Afro: Resurrection, just in case you haven't seen it...)

Also in Resurrection, supposedly one MUST have the number TWO headband to even be able to ask for a challenge, thus being the only person on the face on the planet able to even HURT the number one "god".  Yet, Afro's "resurrected" father easily shows us that the entire thing is a giant charade and complete farce when he stabs her without ANY headband and lands a mortal blow.  What a bunch of idiots wasting their lives away on pieces of cloth, including Afro's Dad who may have in fact known however (who knows though)...

Comment: Probably to very same degree of idiocracy in Monty Python and the Holy Grail where everybody at the end gets hauled in paddy wagons.

Answer (score -1):

Well the new number one in ressurection (forgot her name think its okiku) takes the number one headband without the number two but expects afro to get the number two first although it seems its not required

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, and it's difficult to make sense of what you're trying to say with this run-on sentence.

Answer (score -2):

No, You need the number two or have killed the number two to kill the number 1.

Afro's dad's clone 'killed' afro thus, making him the number two. Thats what let him kill Sio.